# Win10でwslのファイルシステム上に作成したファイルをすぐにwslで参照したい

Tags: wsl

Win10でwslのホームディレクトリ下(※1)にファイルを作成しても、すぐにはwslで参照できません。
Win10を再起動すると、wslからも見えるようになります。
再起動せずに、即座にwslから参照する方法があれば教えてください。

※1　Win10でのWSLユーザのディレクトリ

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\yyyyyyyy

        XXXXXはWinユーザ
        yyyyyyyはWSLユーザのHOMEディレクトリ
```

WSLのバージョンは以下のとおりです。
/etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

---

解決しました。らっしーさん、どうもありがとうございました。
実はいろいろあって時間がかかりました。

- 1903を当てる
  問題なし
- \wsl$\ディストリビューション名
  問題あり

  - `wslconfig /l`でディストリビューション名を調べる

  ```
  Windows Subsystem for Linux ディストリビューション:
  Ubuntu-18.04 (既定)
  Ubuntu
  ```

  - エクスプローラで`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04`をアクセス
    ★ KERNEL_MODE_HEAP_CORRUPTION でブルー画面、再起動される。
  - KERNEL_MODE_HEAP_CORRUPTIONの調査
    [バグ チェック 0x13A:カーネル_モード_ヒープ_破損](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp//windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x13a--kernel-mode-heap-corruption)が引っ掛かった。
    詳細はよく理解できなかったが、何かが破損しているよう。
- 修復
  問題なし

  - `wslconfig /upgrade Ubuntu-18.04`の実行
    ディスクのチェック方法や修復方法がわからなかったので、思い切ってファイルシステムの変換を行うことにした。
    これでエラーなら`WSL`の再構築を覚悟して、実行した。
    夕方開始して、寝るときにもまだ終わっていない。朝起きても終わっていなかったが、うっかりエンターキーを押下したら正常終了のメッセージがでた。※実際はもっと早く終了していたのかもしれない。
- \wsl$\ディストリビューション名　を再度実行
  問題なし
  Win10で作成したファイルをWSLから即時アクセスすることができた。

---

エクスプローラで`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04`を開いたときにPCが落ちたときは(３回ぐらい試したましたが全滅)、最悪の事態を覚悟しましたが、おかげ様で、やりたいことができるようになりました。

Comment: ご自身が実際に試された、より具体的な解決法を投稿するのに[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)が使えますので、是非お試しください。信用度も別途にもらえます :)

Comment: 自己回答してみました。「本当に新しく回答を投稿しますか？」のダイアログが出たので、少しためらいました。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

そのような操作はWSLのサポート外です。

WSL上の/以下のファイルシステムは、NTFSのファイルシステムを利用していますが、NTFSをそのまま使っているわけではありません。WindowsとLinuxでのファイルシステムの違い(大文字小文字を区別する・しない等)を吸収するために特殊なファイルやフォルダー扱いになっており、不足分の情報を別途持っていたりします。そのため、**Windows上からWSLのファイルシステムとして利用しているNTFS上の領域を直接操作することはサポートされていません。** すぐに見えない程度はまだ良い方で、最悪、ファイルが壊れたり、消えたりして、WSLのディストリビューションが壊れる事があります。

Windows 10 1903から`\\wsl$\ディストリビューション名`でWindowsから(サポートされた動作として)操作することができるようになりましたので、このパス経由でアクセスし、ディレクトリ等の作成をしてください。

Answer (score 2):

自己回答です。
らっしーさんの回答のとおり、以下の手順で問題は解決しました。
Win10側でWSLへファイルを送り込むと、WSL側ですぐ参照できるようになりました。

【手順】
 - 1903を当てる
 - \wsl$\ディストリビューション名でアクセス
`subst S: \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\ユーザ名`でドライブを割り当てています。
※ネットワークドライブの割り当ては使えませんでした

【注意】
　**調子にのって、WSL側でCソース整形(`clang-format -i`)、Win10側でソース修正を繰り返していたら、何回目かに`KERNEL_MODE_HEAP_CORRUPTION`でWin10が落ちました。

　自己責任で排他しないと危険です**が、普通に使っている分には快適です。

---

Win10起動直後に、ドライブ割り当て(`subst S: \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\ユーザ名`)を実行すると`KERNEL_MODE_HEAP_CORRUPTION`でWin10が落ちました。
　それ以降は、WSL側を起動し、`sudo service ssh start`を実行した後にドライブ割り当てを行うようにしています。因果関係は説明できませんが、Win10が落ちるのが嫌なので「おまじない」と思ってこの手順を踏んでいいます。

Answer (score 1):

求めている方法とは逆かもしれませんが WSL 側から Windows の フォルダは
`/mnt/c/Users/[ユーザ名]` でアクセスできます。

[Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) を開いたときのデフォルトは
このディレクトリになっています。

Visual Studio Code で ファイルを編集しながら、ターミナルで ビルド＆実行していますが
不安定な事はありません。

WSL の Ubunto 側で `code .` と 打鍵すると Windows 側で Visual Studio Code が起動して WSL 側のファイルをリモートアクセスで編集できるのでとても便利です。

C,C++ の開発を WSL + Windows + Visual Studio Code で行うのを試してみてください。

Comment: k systemさん、コメントありがとうございます。確かに便利そうですね。試してみます。「Win側のファイルをエクスプローラでWSLのファイルシステムにドラッグ＆ドロップしたい」というのがこの質問の目的、背景でした。